# str.CharAt is not a function - when trying to access server route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm not sure what I did, but I broke something. Trying to deploy an API to Heroku. Everything was fine locally but then I guess I did something wrong and now it's all broken. It works when I go just `localhost:5000` and displays that page (which just says "hello world") but when I try to access anything with the API parameters eg: `localhost:5000/data/2018-10/gen6ou` it just sits. No error is shown in the console. In the terminal, where i ran the command: `node index.js` it displays: `str.charAt is not a function` but does not break the connection or anything.

`index.js`

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const pool = require("./db"); //stores super secret db info
const cors = require("cors");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5500;

// middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json()); // => req.body
app.use(express.static('public')); //index.html, just says 'hello world'

// get the data
app.get("/data/:date/:tier", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { date, tier } = req.params;
        const allData = await pool.query(
            "SELECT * FROM smogon_usage_stats WHERE date=$1 AND tier=$2", 
            [date, tier]
            );
        const results = allData.rows;
        const output = { "data": Object.fromEntries(
            results.map(
                item => [item.pokemon, item]
                ))
            };
        res.json(output);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    };
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "usage_server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "pg": "^8.5.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.16.0",
    "npm": "6.14.11"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

`db.js`

```js
const { Pool } = require('pg');
require("dotenv").config();

const devConfig = `postgresql://${process.env.PG_USER}:
${process.env.PG_PASSWORD}@${process.env.PG_HOST}:
${process.env.PG_PORT}/${process.env.PG_DATABASE}`;

const proConfig = {
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL
};

const conn = new Pool({
  connectionString: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? devConfig : proConfig
});

module.exports = conn;
```

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace for this error?

Comment: Is your `devConfig` really a multiline string? I could imagine that causing problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In production, your database config object is invalid - the `connectionString` contains another *object* (the `proConfig`).

You seem to be looking for either

```
const devConfig = {
  connectionString: `postgresql://${process.env.PG_USER}:${process.env.PG_PASSWORD}@${process.env.PG_HOST}:${process.env.PG_PORT}/${process.env.PG_DATABASE}`
};

const proConfig = {
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL
};

const conn = new Pool(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? devConfig : proConfig);
```

or

```
const connectionString = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
  ? process.env.DATABASE_URL
  : `postgresql://${process.env.PG_USER}:${process.env.PG_PASSWORD}@${process.env.PG_HOST}:${process.env.PG_PORT}/${process.env.PG_DATABASE}`;

const conn = new Pool({ connectionString });
```